# Wikipedia API returning sorted data instead of random data

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am trying to generate random articles from a category using the Wikipedia API sandbox.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&format=jsonfm&rnnamespace=0&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category%3ATeam%20sports&gcmnamespace=0

But whenever the query is made articles were returned in alphabetical order rather than randomly. **Also the same set of articles is returned each time**. The number of articles retrieved each time is much lower than the total number of articles in the category. What is the bug in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make sense to use a list API with a generator. Most query APIs take a set of pagenames/ids as input, and this parameter can be replaced with a generator. List APIs take no such input so they won't be affected.

What actually happens is that the random API generates a single page (since its limit parameter defaults to 1) under the `random` key; that page is properly random and changes with every request, but it isn't limited to the category (list APIs don't work that way). The return from the generator API (which is, of course, not random) is displayed under the `pages` key, since any pages passed to the random API in the `title` parameter are simply returned under that key.

What you could do is call [Special:RandomInCategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory) (there is no API equivalent yet) and just retry until you get a main namespace page.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Random

> Pages are listed in a fixed sequence, only the starting point is random. This means that if, for example, "Main Page" is the first random page on your list, "List of fictional monkeys" will always be second, "List of people on stamps of Vanuatu" third, etc.

Comment: I am getting the same set of articles each time. By the definition i guess i should be getting different set of articles each time at least.

Answer (score 1):

The generator is giving you a small input set, and I don't think random works well with a generator input...

Answer (score 0):

Passing in `random` as the value to the `list` parameter does not affect the order of articles, but rather the articles that are returned.

This means that a different "random" set of articles will be returned each time, and not necessarily mean that they will be presented in a random order.

On a related note, the most likely explanation for why you are getting the same set of data on each query is that you have limited the scope of your query (using the other parameters) such that the number of total possible articles is less than the maximum  number (`rnlimit`), so the same set is returned each time.

Either limit the number of articles returned, or broaden the scope of your search query.

See this query for a working example: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=5&format=json

You can find more information regarding usage on the [MediaWiki documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Random).

Comment: The total number of articles possible is not less than rnlimit. I verified this by retrieving the next set of article using the continue parameter. I am always getting the same set of articles. How to generate a random set of articles from the same category?